# Triggering job takes a long time to recognize that other job is finished

Tags: jenkins

I have two jobs.  Let's call them jobA and jobB.

JobA, using the Parameterized Triggers plugin, calls jobB and waits for it to be done.

Sometimes it takes a long time for jobA to recognize that jobB is finished.  It can take 5, 10, and sometimes over 50 minutes after jobB is finished for jobA to stop saying "Waiting for the completion of jobB" and continue on.

I would like to eliminate this unnecessary delay so that my builds are more timely.